# How to debug parts of my C mathematical program?

Tags: c

I'm stuck on this code and have searched the web for an answer and I didn't find anything.

The code get compiled but in options 1 and 2 the code doesn't get the real answer, I don't know if the problem is about the all thing like double and float or because of a stupid mistake.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.141

void twoPoints ();
void hypotenuseInTriangular ();
void areaAndScopeInCircle (float radius);
void areaOfSquare ();
void areaOfRectangle ();


int main()
{
    int num=0 ;
    float radius=0;
    double ans1= 0,x1=0,x2=0,y1=0,y2=0;
    printf("hello friend, please enter one of the options: \n");
    printf("press 1 to calculate length between two points\n");
    printf("press 2 to calculate hypotenuse in right tringle \n");
    printf("press 3 to calculate area and scope in circle \n");
    printf("press 4 to calculate area of square \n");
    printf("press 5 to calculate area of rectangle \n");
    printf("press 6 to exit from the code \n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    switch (num)
    {
        case 1:
            twoPoints(x1,x2,y1,y2);
            break;
        case 2:
            hypotenuseInTriangular();
            break;
        case 3:
            areaAndScopeInCircle (radius);
            break;
        case 4:
            areaOfSquare();
            break;
        case 5:
            areaOfRectangle();
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("bye!\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("not good number \n");
            break;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
} 
/**
this funcion calculate the length between two points.
input: two points (x1,y1) (x2,y2).
output: the length between them.
*/
void twoPoints (double x1,double x2,double y1,double y2)
{
    double ans1=0,calculate1=0,calculate2=0;
    printf("enter  two integer points like this: x1 y1 x2 y2\n");
    scanf("%1f %1f %1f %1f",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
    calculate1 = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2);
    calculate2 = (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2);
    calculate1 += calculate2;
    calculate2 = sqrt(calculate1);
    printf("the length between your two points is: %f\n",calculate2);
}

/**
this funcion calculate the hypotenuse in right tringle using two ribs.
input: two integer numbers of the tringle.
output: the hypotenuse length.
*/
void hypotenuseInTriangular (double sideA,double sideB)
{
    double sideC=0.0,sum=0.0;
    printf("enter two ribs from the triangle: \n");
    scanf("%1f %1f",&sideA,&sideB);
    sum = (sideA * sideA + sideB * sideB);
    sideC = sqrt(sum);
    printf("your hyptenuse is %f \n",sideC);
}
/**
this funcion calculate area and scope using radius.
input: a radius number.
output: the area and the scope of this circle.
*/
void areaAndScopeInCircle (float radius)
{
    float area = 0,scope =0;
    printf("enter radius: \n");
    scanf("%f",&radius);
    area = PI * radius * radius;
    scope = PI * radius * 2;
    printf("the area of your circle is: %.1f\n",area);
    printf("the scope of your circle is: %.1f\n",scope);

}
/**
this funcion calculate area of square using two ribs.
input:  two integer numbers.
output: the area of the square.
*/
void areaOfSquare (int rib)
{
    printf("enter one of the square rib: \n");
    scanf("%d",&rib);
    printf("the area of your square is: %d\n",(rib*rib));
}
/**
this funcion calculate area of rectangle using two ribs.
input: two integer numbers.
output: the area of the rectangle.
*/
void areaOfRectangle (int length,int width)
{
    printf("enter length and than width\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&length,&width);
    printf("the area of your rectangle is: %d\n",(length*width));
}
```

Comment: You did not give parameters to the `hypotenuseInTriangular();` call.

Comment: Good God you searched *all* the internet?

Comment: Please tell us what you expected, what you tried and what happened. PEople can try this out by themselves but if you ask in that fashion, the answers will be much more focussed and useful for you.

Comment: When your program calls `twoPoints(x1,x2,y1,y2)`, those variables have all been assigned the value 0 and are never changed. So as written, this program will only ever calculate the distance between (0,0) and (0,0).

Comment: @MPI_What all of the internet!

Comment: The math in options 1 and 2 look fine. What outputs are you getting for options 1 and 2? One thing I see is you aren't actually setting any nonzero values for any of the input variables.

Comment: in those two options i tried to get the answer, once the length between two points and once the hypotenuse in right triangle. @NoufalIbrahim

Comment: didnt understand what you wrote @TimPierce

Comment: the outputs in those two options is 0.0000 i do not understand why, sorry about it, as im wrote, im new in program @choward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function `twoPoints()` you have used incorrect format specifiers with

```
scanf("%1f %1f %1f %1f",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
```

these could be typos or copying errors because a `1` (numeral one) looks a lot like an `l` (letter ell). The line should be

```
scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
```

and after making this correction the function works.

Note that the lower-case `L` in the format specifier stands for `long`. In `scanf()` and friends, for a `float` variable input you use `%f` and for a `double` variable you use `%lf`. However in `printf()` and friends, you use `%f` for `double` and for `float` because any `float` argument is automatically promoted to `double`.

Answer (score 2):

In your function `twoPoints` -

```
 scanf("%1f %1f %1f %1f",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
```

instead of above try this -

```
 scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);       // %lf not %1f
```

And similar in other funcitons .

**Note** - Also , your function when defined expect arguments , but when you call them in `main` , you don't pass them any arguments. Such as this -

```
hypotenuseInTriangular();        // expects 2 double arguments
```

Call them with correct arguments  , and also declare prototypes correctly .

Comment: Doesn't address another main issue of this code which is the lack of variables being passed to the functions?

Comment: @MPI_What I didn't have a good look on code. Now on seeing I have mentioned it . Thanks !! :-)

Comment: @ameyCU you just beat me, +1

Comment: @MPI_What the data is entered in the function. It's not good code, but after making the correction it works.

Comment: @WeatherVan Yep, fair point. I also didn't read it thoroughly enough!

Comment: thank you so much! you don't know how much you help me!!! just one more question - what is this key ???

Comment: @blackfish  `%lf` is specifier to read `double` in `scanf` function .

Comment: @ameyCU yes now i know, but what key is in the keyboard?

Comment: @blackfish What key ?? It is `L` is smaller case .

Comment: @ameyCU oh right :) again thank you so much!!